# Can you prove Unions and intersections are treated unsymmetrically in the definition of rings?

Tags: measure-theory

In the book of measure theory by Paul R.Halmos he said " unions and intersections are treated unsymmetrically in the definition of rings, while for instance, it is true that a ring is closed under the formation of intersections it is not true that a class of sets closed under the formation of intersections and differences is necessarily closed under the formation of unions" .
I was wondering how would you prove that?

Answer (score 3):

You prove that by giving an example of a set of subsets that is closed under intersections and differences but not closed under unions.

E.g. on any set $X$ with at least two points, the family $\{\{x\}: x \in X\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$ is such.

so being closed under union and differences (a ring) implies being closed under intersections, but being closed under intersections and differences does *not* imply been closed under unions. So we cannot interchange the rôles of union and intersection, which is the point Halmos is making.
He tries to give a "minimal" set of conditions, because that makes it easier (less work) to check that a family is indeed a ring. So here he goes on to note that he also could have asked for closedness under intersections, proper differences and disjoint unions instead. So there are conditions that we can add to closed under intersections to get a ring, but just closed under differences won't do.